# java inputStream read large html only one tag at a time

Tags: java, android, file-io, inputstream, fileinputstream

I have an android app that works with large html files (a whole book). Reading whole html files is not a good idea for many reasons (performance, memory usage, etc.)

I prefer to read the file one tag at a time if it's possible. My Html file looks like this

```
<main_tag>some text here</main_tag>
<main_tag><sub_tag>something</sub_tag><sub_tag>another thing</sub_tag><main_tag>
```

My Main tags are h1 ... h6 and p. And i want to read my file based on this tags. All the other tags are included in main tags and should be read with main tag.

any idea how can i achieve this? performance is a real issue here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all you need is to use android **xml pull api**, read the documentation about `org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser`

Nirav

Comment: I came to this solution hours ago. It seems to be the best option here. just one thing, how can i start reading from middle of a file? First time user opens the document i show it from the beginning but for next time i want to start reading file from previously seen position.